# Máscaras para telefone e CPF em TextField

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-masked-input

Como posso colocar máscaras para telefone e CPF no `text_field`?

Em **app/views/layouts/application**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>

 <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all%>
 <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
 <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

Em **app/assets/javascript**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(.tel_celular).mask("(99) 99999-9999");
});
```

No `form` de bolsista:

```
<%= f.text_field :tel_celular, class: "form-control", class: "span2", id: 'tel_celular' %>
```

Mas não carrega a máscara.

Comment: Acho que o problema é no seletor, tá faltando as aspas `$('.tel_celular')`. O input possui a classe `tel_celular`?

Comment: Sim. Não se pode trabalhar com nomes de classes já existentes ?

Comment: Bem é um dos ítens da classe bolsista melhor dizendo.

Comment: Acho que você está usando a função errado, não? Deveria ter alguma chamada de on_keypress ou algo assim não?!

Comment: Como assim ? É porque estou aprendendo a trabalhar com o rails, e algumas coisas não estou sabendo lidar direito.

Comment: o correto não é: `$(.tel_celular).mask("(99) 99999-9999");` , é: `$('.tel_celular').mask("(99) 99999-9999");`a classe é passada em formato string, da mesma maneira que vc fez para passar a máscara.

Comment: Há 3 erros claros aí: o primeiro é que você não colocou aspas no elemento **.tel_celular**, o segundo é que vc criou duas "class", form-control e span2, o que terá um conflito entre as duas: o correto seria class: "form-control span2", o terceiro, e que vc está tratando a id: 'tel_celular' como um elemento de classe, mas na verdade pelo modelo ele sugere que seja id, no javascript, id deveria ser tratada assim: `'#tel_celular'`.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Máscara de telefones usando jQuery Mask Plugin](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42238/m%c3%a1scara-de-telefones-usando-jquery-mask-plugin)

Comment: Além de possível duplicata, você precisa observar qual é o seu problema e fornecer a informação mais adequada para resolução, por exemplo, você postou o código da linguagem que está gerando o `HTML` da página enquanto seu problema envolve máscaras e `jQuery`, o ideal era você postar apenas o `HTML` gerado e sequer add a tag do `ruby` na pergunta...

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte plugin: [JQuery Mask Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/). Sempre uso ele e atende às minhas necessidades.

Mas tem algumas coisas que você precisa fazer.

**Primeiro**: Certifique-se de que você está fazendo a chamada da função JavaScript na página onde está o input para o qual o filtro será aplicado.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
    $('.js_telefone').mask('(99) 99999-9999');
</script>
```

**Segundo**: Se você for aplicar o input baseado na classe deverá usar como descrito anteriormente, se for baseado no substitua o "." por "#":

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
    $('#js_telefone').mask('(99) 99999-9999');
</script>
```

**Terceiro**: Vá até o imput onde o filtro será aplicado e declare a classe. No caso desse exemplo será 'js_telefone':

```
<input type="text" class="jstelefone">
```

Obs: Lembre-se de importar o script do plugin na página.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite ,

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> // Mascaras Javascript

function mascara(o,f){
    v_obj=o
    v_fun=f
    setTimeout("execmascara()",1)
}
function execmascara(){
    v_obj.value=v_fun(v_obj.value)
}

function id( el ){
 return document.getElementById( el );
}

// aqui começa as mascaras 

function mtel(v){ //MASCARA PARA TELEFONE

    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");             //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/g,"($1) $2"); //Coloca parênteses em volta dos dois primeiros dígitos
    v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/,"$1-$2");    //Coloca hífen entre o quarto e o quinto dígitos
    return v;
}


function mcpf(v){  //MASCARA PARA CPF

    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"")                    //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v=v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2")       //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
    v=v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2")       //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
                                             //de novo (para o segundo bloco de números)
    v=v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$/,"$1-$2") //Coloca um hífen entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
    return v;
}

function mcnpj(v){  //MASCARA PARA CNPJ

    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"")                    //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
 
  v=v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/,"$1.$2")
  v=v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2")
     v=v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1/$2")         
     v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{2})$/,"$1-$2");    //Coloca o . antes dos últimos 3 dígitos, e antes do verificador 
    return v;
}

function mie(v){  //MASCARA PARA CNPJ

    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"")                    //Remove tudo o que não é dígito        
     v=v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2")
   v=v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2")
   v=v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2")
    return v;
}


function mrg(v){  //MASCARA PARA RG

    //  v=v.replace( /\s/g, '' );                  //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
 // v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{7})$/,"$1.$2");     //Coloca o . antes dos últimos 3 dígitos, e antes do verificador
    //  v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/,"$1.$2");    //Coloca o . antes dos últimos 3 dígitos, e antes do verificador
    //  v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d)$/,"$1-$2");       //Coloca o - antes do último dígito
  
 v=v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/,"$1.$2")       //Coloca um ponto entre o segundo e o terceiro dígitos
    v=v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2")     
 v=v.replace(/(\d{5})(\d)/,"$1.$2")     
 v=v.replace(/(\d{9})(\d)/,"$1-$2")       
    return v;
}

function mcep(v){  //MASCARA PARA CEP

    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"")                      //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v=v.replace(/^(\d{5})(\d)/,"$1-$2")         //Esse é tão fácil que não merece explicações
    return v;
}

function mcartao(v){ //MASCARA PARA CARTAO

    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"")                    //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v=v.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/,"$1.$2")       //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
    v=v.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/,"$1.$2")       //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
 v=v.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/,"$1.$2")       //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
 v=v.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/,"$1.$2")       //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
    return v;
}

function mdata(v){ // MASCARA PARA DATA 

    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");                    //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v=v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/,"$1/$2");
    v=v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/,"$1/$2");
    return v;
}

function mvalor(v){  //MASCARA PARA VALOR EM $$

    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");//Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{8})$/,"$1.$2");//coloca o ponto dos milhões
    v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{5})$/,"$1.$2");//coloca o ponto dos milhares
 
    v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{2})$/,"$1,$2");//coloca a virgula antes dos 2 últimos dígitos
    return v;
}

function mvalor(v){  //MASCARA PARA VALOR EM $$

    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");//Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{8})$/,"$1.$2");//coloca o ponto dos milhões
    v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{5})$/,"$1.$2");//coloca o ponto dos milhares
 
    v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{2})$/,"$1,$2");//coloca a virgula antes dos 2 últimos dígitos
    return v;
}

function memail(v){

  v=v.replace( /\s/g, '' );
  return v;
}

window.onload = function(){ // FUNCAO QUE É ACIONADO AO CARREGAR A PAGINA ( WINDOW.ONLOAD )

 id('txtCel').onkeyup = function(){ //ATRIBUI O CAMPO COM ID txtCel A MASCARA DE TELEFONE
  mascara( this, mtel );
 }
 
 id('txtFixo').onkeyup = function(){ //ATRIBUI O CAMPO COM ID txtFixo A MASCARA DE TELEFONE
  mascara( this, mtel );
 }
 
 id('txtComercial').onkeyup = function(){ //ATRIBUI O CAMPO COM ID txtComercial A MASCARA DE TELEFONE
  mascara( this, mtel );
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label col-md-3">Celular</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
         <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="txtCel" name="txtCel" value="<?php echo $_POST['txtCel'];?>" maxlength="15" >
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
             
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label col-md-3">Telefone fixo</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
         <input type="text" id="txtFixo" name="txtFixo" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_POST['txtFixo'];?>" maxlength="15" >
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
       
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label col-md-3">Telefone Comercial</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
         <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="txtComercial" name="txtComercial" value="<?php echo $_POST['txtComercial'];?>" maxlength="15">
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div><!--::: ROW :: -->
```

Segue arquivo de teste funcionando.

https://mega.nz/#!3pc1ADTJ!xpX-qug03hCbJJ5UhQ1gqhc2JkP7E1MpKRMIYkXTjxw

Qualquer coisa , posta ae.

Comment: Muito. Eu achei que só faltou o limitador do tamanho ou aqui não deu certo, eu acho que o Regex tem como limitar o tamanho, caso você atualize a resposta e de certo eu dou um UP

Answer (score 0):

É possivel usar caracteres opcionais

```
 $('.tel_celular').mask('(99) 9999-9999?9').focusout(function() {
      var phone, element;
      element = $(this);
      element.unmask();
      phone = element.val().replace(/\D/g, '');
      if( phone.substring(0, 1) === '0' ) {
           element.mask("9999-999-9999");
      } else if (phone.length > 10) {
           element.mask("(99) 99999-999?9");
      } else {
           element.mask("(99) 9999-9999?9");
      }
 }).trigger('focusout');
```

Answer (score -1):

Quando for utilizar o Jquery para classes começe com ponto

```
   $(.tel_celular).mask("(99) 99999-9999");
```

Quando for retornar de acordo com o id, utilize #

```
   $(#tel_celular).mask("(99) 99999-9999");
```

Nesse seu caso, faltou declarar a classe como tel_celular no lugar de span2 ex.:

```
   <%= f.text_field :tel_celular, class: "form-control", class: "tel_celular", id: 'tel_celular' %>
```

Caso utilize essa classe span2 para os telefones, é só mudar la no javascript para:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(.span2).mask("(99) 99999-9999");
    });
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou. Não consegue carregar as máscaras dentro text_field.

Comment: Já não sei mais o que posso fazer para aparecer estas máscaras.

Comment: @Fernanda você relacionou o arquivo jquery mask a seu projeto? As outras funções do jquery estão funcionando?

Comment: Bem instalei a gem jQuery Mask no GemFile, coloquei a chamada na application no caminho: app\view\layout assim <script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js"/></script>   e no applicatio.js  isso: $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tel").mask("(99)99999-9999");
  
 });
e no form de view : <%= f.text_field :tel_celular, class: "form-control", class: "tel", id: "tel" %>   modifiquei as chamadas, ao invés de de tel_celular para tel para ver se modificava, mas ainda nada.

Comment: Estou presa com esta parte do sistema.

Comment: @Fernanda complementei com algumas informações na resposta acima, pode verificar?

Comment: Respondendo uma de suas perguntas acima no meu layout está com esta tag:  <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>.

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou :(   Tentei com as opções que vc falou, fiz o download do arquivo no git, mudei para inputmask para testar, mas nada, não consigo entender o porque não puxa a mascara.

Comment: Também estou começando a desvendar as funcionalidades do Ruby on Rails. Não sei se é porque estou usando a versão 3.2.13 do Rails.

Comment: O alerta funcionou ? alert("document ready");

Comment: @Fernanda o Rails não interfere em nada a questão das máscaras, essa é uma questão somente do jQuery e o plugin que esta usando. Verifique no seu navegador se existe algum erro de JavaScript, normalmente apertando a tecla `F12` e a opção `Console`, se tiver algum erro coloque aqui por favor.

Comment: @wcj, o elemento deve ser passado como string.

Comment: @IvanFerrer e o que isso tem a ver?

Comment: @wcj, o que tem a ver é que você não está passando como string o nome da classe: `$(.tel_celular)` mude para `$('.tel_celular')`, além disso, vc tem que ver se é um class ou se é id, id: `$('#tel_celular')` <> classe: `$('.tel_celular')`