# Campo máscara jQuery para celular/telefone fixo com nono digito

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte jQuery

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#telefone").mask("(99) 9 9999-9999");
   $("#celular").mask("(99) 9 9999-9999");
});
```

Porém, ao digitar o numero no campo, se for telefone fixo por exemplo, ele zera o campo, porque o fixo não tem o nono digito. Como eu consigo ajustar essa questão?

Comment: Já existe uma resposta aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42242/46523

Comment: Ótimo, muito obrigado! :)