# Expressão Regular em JavaScript para Telefone com DDI

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Estou com dificuldades de entender a lógica dos Regex, e nao acho códigos que componham a mascara completa de telefone com DDI, DDD e telefone com 8 e 9 digitos com mudança do hifen ao digitar direto no campo utilizando por exemplo o evento onkeyup.

Segue a mascara +99 (99) 9999-9999 ou +99 (99) 99999-9999

Comment: Sempre vai o DDI? da pra fazer assim também: [Máscara de telefones usando jQuery Mask Plugin](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/112543/91)

Answer (score 14):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte expressão:

```
/^(?:\+)[0-9]{2}\s?(?:\()[0-9]{2}(?:\))\s?[0-9]{4,5}(?:-)[0-9]{4}$/
```

Difícil de entender? A mesma foi gerada através da ferramenta [Simple Regex Language](https://simple-regex.com/):

```
begin with literally "+",
digit exactly 2 times,
whitespace optional,
literally "(", digit exactly 2 times, literally ")",
whitespace optional,
digit between 4 and 5 times,
literally "-",
digit exactly 4 times,
must end
```

Acredito que desta forma ela fique auto-explicativa.

Comment: +1 pelo Simple Regex Language. Sensacional

Comment: @ArthurMenezes, pois é, ela já me salvou muitas vezes.

Comment: Eu só espero que eles não estejam falando que `\s` seja *whitespace* de `" "`

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert, qualquer espaçamento, como é padrão do regex. Vide documentação ("*This matches any whitespace character. This includes a space, tab or new line.*")

Answer (score 4):

O regex abaixo válida a máscara que você precisa

#### JS

```
var RegExp = /\+\d{2}\s\(\d{2}\)\s\d{4,5}-?\d{4}/g;
var t = "+99 (99) 99999-9999";
RegExp.test(t); //true

var t2 = "+99 (99) 9999-9999";
RegExp.test(t2); //true

var t3 = "+99 (99) 999999-9999";
RegExp.test(t3); //false
```

Answer (score 3):

Pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
var regExp = /^\+?\d{2}?\s*\(\d{2}\)?\s*\d{4,5}\-?\d{4}$/g;
var telefone = '+55 (55) 23321-5454';
var resultado = regExp.test(telefone); //retorna true ou false
```

Answer (score 0):

Função para mascara de Telefone com DDI

```
function mTel(tel) {
    tel=tel.replace(/\D/g,"")
    tel=tel.replace(/^(\d)/,"+$1")
    tel=tel.replace(/(.{3})(\d)/,"$1($2")
    tel=tel.replace(/(.{6})(\d)/,"$1)$2")
    if(tel.length == 12) {
        tel=tel.replace(/(.{1})$/,"-$1")
    } else if (tel.length == 13) {
        tel=tel.replace(/(.{2})$/,"-$1")
    } else if (tel.length == 14) {
        tel=tel.replace(/(.{3})$/,"-$1")
    } else if (tel.length == 15) {
        tel=tel.replace(/(.{4})$/,"-$1")
    } else if (tel.length > 15) {
        tel=tel.replace(/(.{4})$/,"-$1")
    }
    return tel;
}
```