# Como validar telefone celular e residencial?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de **validar** o telefone celular e residencial, adicionando o **parenteses** e **traço** **automaticamente**.

**Celular**

*O que eu gostaria:*

Validar se o celular contém o dígito 9 no início e DDD (2 dígitos), totalizando 11 dígitos. Logo, validar se contém 11 dígitos.

Adicionar o parenteses automaticamente e traço.

(51)97654-3389

**E residencial:**

*O que eu gostaria:*

Validar se contém o DDD (2 dígitos), totalizando 10 dígitos. Logo, validar se contém 10 dígitos.

Adicionar o parenteses e traço automaticamente.

(51)3456-5043

Pesquisei sobre **regex** mas não compreendi 100%.

Como poderia fazer isso com JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: Para usar regex é preciso definir o formato dos números. Qualquer caractere diferente que possa variar no formato invalida a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma expressão regular.

> É uma string que define um padrão de busca. É um algoritmo. Podemos
>   dizer que ela é uma linguagem para localização de padrões em texto. Veja: [O que é uma expressão regular?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185301/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-express%C3%A3o-regular)

O JavaScript possui o [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), que retorna `true` ou `false` para sua validação.

A expressão regular que utilizo para validar [telefones brasileiros](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmeros_de_telefone_no_Brasil) é o seguinte:

```
/^\(\d{2}\) \d{4,5}-\d{4}$/gi
{início da linha}({dois dígitos}) {de quatro a cinco dígitos}-{quatro dígitos}{fim da linha}
```

Essa expressão aceitará telefones no formato `(XX) XXXX-XXXX` e `(XX) XXXXX-XXXX`.

Para testar uma string contra ela, pode utilizar o `test()`:

```
const isValidPhone = (phone) => {
  const brazilianPhoneRegex = /^\(\d{2}\) \d{4,5}-\d{4}$/gi;
  return brazilianPhoneRegex.test(phone);
};

isValidPhone("(41) 99778-2914");
// true

isValidPhone("(411) 99778-2914");
// false

isValidPhone("(41) 9778-2914");
// true
```

Se você quiser ser mais permissivo, eu faria de outra maneira. Pegaria o string de input, retiraria tudo que não é numérico e verificaria se ele tem de 10 a 11 dígitos, que é o formato do telefone com DDD de dois dígitos. Isso ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
const isValidPhone = (phone) => {
  const sanitizedPhone = phone.replace(/\D/g,'');
  return sanitizedPhone.length >= 10 && sanitizedPhone.length <= 11;
};

isValidPhone("(41) 99778-2914");
// true

isValidPhone("()41A977B8-----8319");
// true, pois tira todo caractere que não é numérico
```

Para a máscara, pode usar o jQuery, como você mesmo sugeriu. Para não reinventarmos a roda, existem algumas perguntas no Stack Overflow em Português que já responderam ela: [Máscara de telefones usando jQuery Mask Plugin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42238/41056)

Se quiser estender ou testar a expressão regular, eu utilizo bastante o site [RegExr](https://regexr.com).

Comment: Particularmente eu colocaria os espaços e o hífen como opcionais para aumentar o range de possibilidades - partindo do pressuposto que a entrada não venha necessariamente em determinado padrão.

Comment: Não votei, mas acho que o autor da pergunta poderia esclarecer mais os formatos dos números para ambos os casos. Assim seria melhor dar uma resposta precisa.